# How to break a line using a PHP printf code

Tags: php, function, printf

I have the following printf statement

```
printf(
        '<a href="%s" class="button header-right-button">%s</a>',
        esc_url($lets_talk_url),
        __('Let\'s Talk! (541) 515-7154‬', 'autism-transformed')
    );
```

I'm trying to resolve a line break where it instead of:

```
Let's talk! (541) 515-7154
```

I want as output:

```
Let's talk! <br>
(541) 515-7154
```

Thank you

The `<br >` and `\n` dont work

I dont know how to do it

Comment: `<br>` should work if you're displaying it in a web page, `\n` should work on a terminal.

Comment: `\n` only works inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: `'<a href="%s" class="button header-right-button">%s</a>' . "\n"`
or `"<a href=\"%s\" class=\"button header-right-button\">%s</a>\n"`